# Invalid JSON object in IE8 but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, internet-explorer-8

Why is this JSON invalid in ie8 but not in firefox or chrome?  On my callback I parse the results to remove some invalid characters using jquery parser.

```
myStringResults = myStringResults.replace("},]","}]");
myStringResults = myStringResults.replace(/'/g,'"');
var objDoc = $.parseJSON(myStringResults);
```

Message: Invalid JSON:

> [{"id":"4796","parent":"4796","name":"Fname","revision":"1","date":"Mar
>   1, 2013 3:44:22 PM","author":"Silva, Jeffery
>   M","filename":"C:\Users\jmsilva\Desktop\VOC
>   pres.pdf","type":"0"},{"id":"4797","parent":"4797","name":"Fname","revision":"1","date":"Mar
>   1, 2013 3:50:46 PM","author":"Silva, Jeffery
>   M","filename":"C:\Users\jmsilva\Desktop\testUpload.doc","type":"0"}]

Comment: I just tried that in the IE9 console in IE8 mode and it worked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your backslashes should be escaped as `\\`. While some browsers are willing to accept that `\` followed by any character that doesn't make a special combination should be treated as a literal, it's unsafe to rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use a tool like this to validate:

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/